# php mysql query outfile

Tags: php, mysql, into-outfile

I am trying to create a script that runs on my database. The query itself works fine in phpmyadmin but need to be able to run it elsewhere. So my idea was, put it into a php script.

My query looks like this:

```
SET @sql_text =
CONCAT ("SELECT
`table1`.`field1`,
`table2`.`field2`

FROM `table1`,`table2`

WHERE
`table1`.`field1`=`table2`.`field2`

 into outfile '/pathtofolder/myresult-"
   , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d-%H:%i')
   , ".csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
    "    );

PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE s1;

DROP PREPARE s1;
```

Now I seem to run into trouble trying to get this into php. My attempt:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "databasename";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = 'SET @sql_text =
CONCAT ("SELECT
`table1`.`field1`,
`table2`.`field2`

FROM `table1`,`table2`

WHERE
`table1`.`field1`=`table2`.`field2`

 into outfile '/pathtofolder/myresult-"
   , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d-%H:%i')
   , ".csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
    "    );

PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE s1;

DROP PREPARE s1;'

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Unfortunatly this does not seem to work. What am I overlooking?

Comment: looking at the syntax highlighting above suggests you need to escape the single quotes within the sql statement

Comment: Ok, I did use escape characters end still nothing. Then I added a ; to the end of the statement and now it finally does something... unfortunatly it does this: 

    Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text; EXECUTE s1; DROP PREPARE s1' at line 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the sql is within single quotes but contains single quotes you would need to escape them using the backslash.

```
$sql = 'SET @sql_text =
CONCAT ("SELECT
`table1`.`field1`,
`table2`.`field2`

FROM `table1`,`table2`

WHERE
`table1`.`field1`=`table2`.`field2`

 into outfile \'/pathtofolder/myresult-"
   , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), \'%Y%m%d-%H:%i\')
   , ".csv\'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY \'|\'
    "    );

PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE s1;

DROP PREPARE s1;'
```

Comment: Even with that correction it does not seem to do anything. It does not echo succes or fail and even if I deliberatly put in the wrong username or password it does not kick an error. Just does not seem to run at all. Am I overlooking something else?